# Must Declare the scalar variable "Post_ID"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this error "Must Declare the scalar variable "Post_ID" if i try to update 2 different ID's in my table.  In other words, i can update as many times as i need to for example ID # 25 but if i try to update ID # 26 then i get the error above.  My insert function works fine only my update function.  Pls. help and i appreciate your time.  Note, the DateKeyNames = ID.  Here is my code for the update only:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE MyTable SET Post_ID=@Post_ID, Date=@Date, Description=@Description WHERE ID=@ID";

            TextBox myTextBox11 = GV_InlineEditing.Rows[0].FindControl("GV_Post_ID") as TextBox;
            TextBox myTextBox22 = GV_InlineEditing.Rows[0].FindControl("TextBox2") as TextBox;
            TextBox myTextBox33 = GV_InlineEditing.Rows[0].FindControl("TextBox3") as TextBox;

            if (myTextBox11 != null)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Post_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = myTextBox11.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                TextBox GV_Post_ID = GV_InlineEditing.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("GV_Post_ID") as TextBox;

            }


            if (myTextBox22 != null)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = myTextBox22.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                TextBox GV_Post_ID = GV_InlineEditing.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("Date") as TextBox;

            }


            if (myTextBox33 != null)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = myTextBox33.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                TextBox GV_Post_ID = GV_InlineEditing.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("Description") as TextBox;

            }
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(GV_InlineEditing.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text);


            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

        }


        GV_InlineEditing.EditIndex = -1;
        BindData();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is somewhat faulty:

```
if (myTextBox11 != null)
{
    //add paramter
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Post_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = myTextBox11.Text;
}
else
{
    //declare a different textbox and do not add the SQL parameter
    TextBox GV_Post_ID = GV_InlineEditing.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("GV_Post_ID") as TextBox;
}
```

This pattern is repeated for `myTextBox22` and `myTextBox33`.

I would suggest this logic instead:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConnectionString").ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE MyTable SET Post_ID=@Post_ID, Date=@Date, Description=@Description WHERE ID=@ID";

TextBox myTextBox11 = GV_InlineEditing.Rows(0).FindControl("GV_Post_ID") as TextBox;
TextBox myTextBox22 = GV_InlineEditing.Rows(0).FindControl("Date") as TextBox;
TextBox myTextBox33 = GV_InlineEditing.Rows(0).FindControl("Description") as TextBox;

if (myTextBox11 == null) {
    //try an alternate control for myTextBox11
    myTextBox11 = GV_InlineEditing.Rows(0).Cells(0).FindControl("GV_Post_ID") as TextBox;
}

if (myTextBox22 == null) {
    //try an alternate control for myTextBox22
    myTextBox22 = GV_InlineEditing.Rows(0).Cells(0).FindControl("Date") as TextBox;
}

if (myTextBox33 == null) {
    //try an alternate control for myTextBox33
    myTextBox33 = GV_InlineEditing.Rows(0).Cells(0).FindControl("Description") as TextBox;
}

if (myTextBox11 != null & myTextBox22 != null & myTextBox33 != null) {
    //all three textbox controls found
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Post_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = myTextBox11.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = myTextBox22.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = myTextBox33.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(GV_InlineEditing.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Text);

    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

**UPDATE**

Add `else` conditions to `Throw New Exception("myTextBox11 is null");` for `myTextBox11`, `myTextBox22`, and `myTextBox33`.

That will allow you to see if both:

```
GV_InlineEditing.Rows(0).FindControl("Date") as TextBox;
```

and:

```
GV_InlineEditing.Rows(0).Cells(0).FindControl("GV_Post_ID");
```

are failing.

Comment: pete, thanks for your help. i have tried your method exactly the way you showed with the exception of this line: myTextBox33 != null and i changed to" myTextBox33 == null " but it does not update the fields, meaning everything stays the same.  the good thing is that i am not getting the error but does not do the update.  what am i missing here?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

I always do something like this like this:

```
 protected void Gridview1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {

            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            int id = Int32.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            TextBox date = (TextBox)row.FindControl("date");

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText =    "update t_your_table " +
                                 "set " +                                 
                                 "date = @date, " +             
                                 " time = @time  where id = @ID "                             


        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = id;           
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = date.Text;
```

You have to get your datakeyname into the variables. That way it will use that field no matter what row is clicked.